# Breaking NSString into lines (to fit desired width)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to get a NSString broken into lines to fit a desired width (as it would happen inside `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:`). Is there a better way to do this than guessing where the breaks would happen in `sizeWithFont`?

Comment: Could you go into a bit more detail on why you need the separated lines? If you just want to draw the string in a given space then this is quite simple.

Comment: I'm creating a background - like the one you get when selecting text - for a label. It's width varies for each line (with different length), so I'll need them separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `NSLayoutManager` is indeed unavailable, you may be stuck with a more inefficient solution: starting with the first word of the string, appending each subsequent word and using the `sizeWithFont:`(etc.) method on the resulting string. When the height of the returned `CGSize` changes, the most recently appended word was the one that caused the line break, and you can thus split the string there.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** This apparently only applies on the Mac platform. Though NSLayoutManager is specifically referenced in the iPhone's String Drawing Guide (as of December, 2009), neither it nor NSAttributedString are available on the iPhone platform. Sorry for the noise.

**Original Response**

[NSLayoutManager](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSLayoutManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is your friend if you're looking to divide up the string itself into lines of a certain width, with a given set of attributes (ie, you need to know the actual places where the string is wrapped).

If you're only looking to wrap lines when *drawing* and you don't care where, NSAttributedString's (AppKit Additions) methods [-drawInRect:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000167-BAJCCACE) or [-drawWithRect:options:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000167-CJBIFBBB) will do just fine.

Comment: Neither NSLayoutManager nor NSAttributedString are available on the iPhone.

Comment: I'm not going to draw the lines (immediately), so neither NSAttributedString nor NSString + UIKit additions are going to help.

Comment: Ole: Confusing. NSLayoutManager is specifically referenced in the String Programming Guide in the iPhone Dev Center's library:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/DrawingStrings.html

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Based on the comment below (you can draw the string, but can't draw a background to cover the string), I think your best bet would be to use a UIWebView and use CSS to draw your background.

---

The [NSString UIKit Additions](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:) might fit your needs, particularly

```
- (CGSize)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect withFont:(UIFont *)font 
       lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode;
```

and/or

```
- (CGSize)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect withFont:(UIFont *)font 
       lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
           alignment:(UITextAlignment)alignment;
```

Comment: Check out the comments on the question and Joshua's answer below—drawing the lines isn't the issue. He actually does need to know where the line breaks are, for the purpose of drawing a background that extends only to the end of each line.

Answer (score 1):

**NSLayoutManager** is available since iOS 7. Documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSLayoutManager_Class_TextKit/Reference/Reference.html).