# \n not working in Sklabel SpriteKit

Tags: xcode5, sprite-kit

I have been using the following code in my game. The Problem is that i am unable to make multi-line label in spritekit as i was able to do using CCLabelTTF...... Can Somebody help me. Also i am unable to use either \t or \n in my code... Thanks for the reply in advance

```
SKLabelNode *winner = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Arial"];
winner.text = @"Another\nTest";
winner.fontSize = 32;
winner.fontColor = [SKColor blueColor];
winner.position = CGPointMake(100 , 160);
[self addChild:winner];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that `SKLabelNode` only supports one line of text at a time. I can't find it in the SpriteKit documentation or anywhere else official, but it's mentioned on the 47th slide of [this WWDC presentation.](http://docs.huihoo.com/apple/wwdc/2013/session_502__introduction_to_sprite_kit.pdf) You'll have to use `UILabel` instead, which you can see explained [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557488/ios-multiline-label-in-interface-builder)

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but the second part of this answer bothers me,  "Use UILabel instead."   Last I knew `UILabel` can not be used inside of an `SKScene`, and explained here only explains how to use a `UILabel`, not how to use it in an  `SKScene`.  The only way I can think of is you can capture the rendered contents from a hidden `UILabel`, and place it into a `SKSpriteNode`  (I am actually trying to avoid this approach, which brought me to this question)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem.  I created a drop-in replacement for SKLabelNode called DSMultilineLabelNode that supports word wrap, line breaks, etc.  The underlying implementation draws the string into a graphics context and then applies that to a texture on an SKSpriteNode.

It's available on GitHub at:

https://github.com/downrightsimple/DSMultilineLabelNode

Answer (score 5):

You can use NSLayoutManager to line-break the string to match a desired width, as hinted by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967250/breaking-nsstring-into-lines-to-fit-desired-width).

Note that [NSLayoutManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSLayoutManager_Class_TextKit/Reference/Reference.html) **is available on iOS** beginning with iOS 7.

Answer (score 3):

Like a lot of others I also needed a fix to this problem. My approach was a lot simpler than Chris' solution. I have made a subclass of `SKLabelNode` called `NORLabelNode`.

It's available at [GitHub](https://github.com/nickfalk/NORLabelNode) and there is also a cocoapod available.

It simply creates a set of SKLabelNodes and use these as subnodes. If you want to implement something similar yourself the main gist is this method:

```
- (NSArray *)labelNodesFromText:(NSString *)text{
    NSArray *substrings    = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    NSMutableArray *labelNodes    = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[substrings count]];

    NSUInteger labelNumber    = 0;
    for (NSString *substring in substrings) {
        SKLabelNode *labelNode    = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:self.fontName];
        labelNode.text    = substring;
        labelNode.fontColor    = self.fontColor;
        labelNode.fontSize    = self.fontSize;
        labelNode.horizontalAlignmentMode    = self.horizontalAlignmentMode;
        labelNode.verticalAlignmentMode    = self.verticalAlignmentMode;
        CGFloat y    = self.position.y - (labelNumber * self.fontSize * self.lineSpacing);
        labelNode.position    = CGPointMake(self.position.x, y);
        labelNumber++;
        [labelNodes addObject:labelNode];
    }

    return [labelNodes copy];
}
```

The above is somewhat simplified as the labels also inherit most of the other properties from their parent.

The linespacing can be altered through a CGFloat property. Apart from this is works just like an ordinary `SKLabelNode` and you can change text, color, font, fontSize etc. on the fly whenever you feel like.