# Sprite kit, How to keep text in a SKLabelNode on the screen?

Tags: sprite-kit

How can i have text in a SKLabelNode stay on the screen. When i type more than a few words, it goes off the screen? How do you keep it inside the screens boundaries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-line label in swift 2 sprite-kit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121482/multi-line-label-in-swift-2-sprite-kit)

Answer (score 1):

SKLabelNode does not support multiple lines or text wrapping, hence any text is rendered on a single line which, if long enough will go off the screen.

Refer to the answers in the following questions:

[\n not working in Sklabel SpriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029580/n-not-working-in-sklabel-spritekit)

[Insert line break using SKLabelNode in SpriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179005/insert-line-break-using-sklabelnode-in-spritekit)